# How do I use walletnotify?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, api, json-rpc, wallet-notify

I have bitcoin daemon and I want to use the walletnotify option with a json-rpc call. Some of the examples use a "transaction.sh" file for `walletnotify`. What is it for?

What do I have to write in that sh file, to make walletnotify work for more than 6 confirmations.

Comment: Just put a ruby CLI command in the .sh file to run your ruby script. A .sh file is *basically* a command line.

Comment: Found this thread helpful: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=203438.0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First you must configure your `bitcoin.conf` file for JSON-RPC

```
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcuser=yourusername
rpcpassword=reallystrongpasswordthatsnothis
rpcport=7788
walletnotify=/home/scripts/transaction.sh %s
```

Where `transaction.sh` is some [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) program. One approach is to have it make an `http` request to some process to notify you of the deposit. An example:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -d "txid=$1" http://127.0.0.1/some/route
```

`walletnotify` will execute `transaction.sh` every time you either

- receive bitcoin
- send bitcoin
- when a bitcoin gets its first confirmation

`%s` is the transaction ID or `txid` which gets passed to `transaction.sh`.

Comment: What if I receive more than 1 transaction in a block? Does it spawn a new process/thread using the bash program for each transaction?

Comment: @pferg it spaws for each transaction and for each block. the only question is: what if you receive multiple inputs from multiple outputs within 1 transaction. ist that even a thng? (i send you 10x 5 BTC within 1 transaction. i think you receive 1 OP with 50BTC)

Answer (score 0):

to complement Loourr's answer, `%w` can also be passed to your script, informing you of the wallet in the node that received the funds, since you may have > 1 wallet