# Bitcoin Transaction within source code

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, sending

I am messing with the Bitcoin sourcecode.

Normally when you want to send some BTC you type :

```
./bitcoind sendtoaddress 1ADRESSS 0.001
```

How would you do this in the sourcecode on a recurring basis?

So what code is needed to send a transaction to a specified address each time a block is created? Almost like a tax. and where would this code be placed?

I am learning the Inside of the Bitcoin protocol and C++ so any help would be great.

Comment: So you want a script that will spend your money without asking your permission? It's doable, but very dangerous. YOu would be better off looking at multi-signature or escrow transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `-blocknotify=<cmd>` facility as described under: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin.

This is a nice example of how to use `-walletnotify`: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24483/11221, `-blocknotify` can be configured in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The table of RPC commands can be found in `rpcserver.cpp` in the static array `vRPCCommands`.  From that you can see that the RPC command `sendtoaddress` is implemented by a C++ function named, appropriately enough, `sendtoaddress`.  A quick grep shows this function is defined in `rpcwallet.cpp`, and its work is done by calling `pwalletMain->SendMoney()`.  So `pwallet->SendMoney()` seems like the right function to call.