# How to run a python script when occur incoming transaction in Bitcoin core 0.18?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, python

I want to run a python script when occur an incoming transaction. I think set **zapwallettxes** flag in **bitcoin.conf** but I don't know where set the script path to execute.

Is it possible to execute another executable file or another language script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `walletnotify` setting in bitcoin.conf

It will call the specified script for every transaction received for your own wallets.

```
walletnotify=/some/path/mywalletscript.py
```

Here `mywalletscript.py` will handle the JSON data passed into it.

[Here is a sample walletnotify implementation](https://github.com/damonp/walletnotify/blob/master/walletnotify.php) including database access. It's a bit dated but should give you an idea on how to handle events.

As per [this Bitcointalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1442574.0) you can also hook up handlers for `blocknotify` and `alertnotify` so you can create your own payment system by receiving alerts, checking block confirmations and so on.

Just wire up a `walletnotify` handler via bitcoin.conf as answered [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify) and [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1442574.0).