# How to check if a bitcoin address received a new transaction programmatically?

Tags: blockchain

How can I check if a bitcoin address received a new transaction programmatically?

Here is an example of the API call, but I can't figure out how to get the value of the new transation in API response:

https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1De2yKR7q95R1CV9PhmxA3kcYVa25mDaqj

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a bitcoin-core node to watch for new transactions, and notify you of them.

This is a preferable solution, since you won't have to trust anyone to supply you with the correct info (what if they lie, or are incorrect?), and you will retain your privacy (why dox yourself with respect to which addresses you are interested in, to the API provider and anyone else listening in on your connection?).

You can set the command `-walletnotify=<cmd>` in your bitcoin.conf file, and write a bash script to alert you of the transaction in question, in your preferred manner (write to a log file, send an alert email, blink a light, etc).

For a slightly more in-depth walkthrough of setting this up, see this question: [How do I use walletnotify?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify)

Answer (score 0):

On a bash shell prompt, assuming you have `curl` and `jq` installed:

```
curl https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1De2yKR7q95R1CV9PhmxA3kcYVa25mDaqj | jq -r '.txs | .[] | .hash' | head -1
```

This will give you the most recent txid this address has appeared in.