# How to properly monitor incoming transactions for a specific address with bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I would like to monitor incoming transactions for a single address using

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 1 false false <myaddress>
```

My problem is the returned array will become longer and longer and I cannot output the last 10 incoming transactions using the arguments. I don't want to rely on any online service, rather I want to use the CLI.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `-walletnotify` startup option for bitcoind/bitcoin-qt. This will execute a program whenever the wallet receives a transaction. So you can write a program which is executed for every transaction and looks for ones which have outputs for the addresses you want. Then this program can do whatever to notify you.

Comment: I'm glad for your answer. I was hoping I could give an additional argument to `-walletnotify` for inline commands, but it seems [I have to modify the `conf` to contain a call to a script](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify). I.e. `walletnotify=/home/scripts/transaction.sh %s`. Apparently, the flag only activates the feature. Your answer helped me to get on the right track, though! :)

Comment: @MartinBraun you can use double quotes for inline commands IIUC