# How to check whether bitcoin is deposited or not with RPC API?

Tags: json-rpc

I am developing a new feature in my website that raises a user's level when they deposit to a new bitcoin address.

Using RPC API, I was successful in creating a new wallet address and printing it on the page.

Now, how can I verify that I have deposited bitcoin to the address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use walletnotify?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify)